# RTL/LTR frontend switcher

Tags: front-end, customization

I have a theme that supports RTL. When **Appearance->Theme settings->Right-to-Left (RTL) text orientation** is enabled theme switches correctly. But I want to add to the main menu 2 items to switch orientation from frontend:

1. RTL - switch theme to RTL mode
2. LTR - switch theme to LTR mode

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I resolved it in this way. Let's say that we have a CSS-file **rtl.css**, which contains rules for right-to-left content direction.

Add menu items: **Appearance->Menus->Select a menu to edit->Edit menus->Custom links**.

1. *URL - ?language=rlt* (or something like this), *Link text - RTL* (for example)
2. *URL - ?language=ltr*, *Link text - LTR*

Create a plugin:

```
add_action('init', 'get_check');

function get_check(){
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }

    if($_GET['language'] == 'rtl'){
        $_SESSION['rtl']=true;
    }

    if($_SESSION['rtl']){
        wp_enqueue_style( 'tmpl_rtl_css', get_template_directory_uri().'/rtl.css',array('tmpl_dir_css') );      
    }

    if($_GET['language'] == 'ltr'){
        session_destroy ();
        wp_dequeue_style('tmpl_rtl_css');
    }
}
```

There need checking, but solution is something like this.